# Classifiers and Numpy Array

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, data-science

```
from __future__ import print_function

from builtins import range
from builtins import object
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from past.builtins import xrange

class TwoLayerNet(object):
    """
    A two-layer fully-connected neural network. The net has an input dimension of
    D* (correction), a hidden layer dimension of H, and performs classification over C classes.
    We train the network with a softmax loss function and L2 regularization on the
    weight matrices. The network uses a ReLU nonlinearity after the first fully
    connected layer.
    In other words, the network has the following architecture:
    input - fully connected layer - ReLU - fully connected layer - softmax
    The outputs of the second fully-connected layer are the scores for each class.
    """

    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size, std=1e-4):
        """
        Initialize the model. Weights are initialized to small random values and
        biases are initialized to zero. Weights and biases are stored in the
        variable self.params, which is a dictionary with the following keys:
        W1: First layer weights; has shape (D, H)
        b1: First layer biases; has shape (H,)
        W2: Second layer weights; has shape (H, C)
        b2: Second layer biases; has shape (C,)
        Inputs:
        - input_size: The dimension D of the input data.
        - hidden_size: The number of neurons H in the hidden layer.
        - output_size: The number of classes C.
        """
        self.params = {}
        self.params['W1'] = std * np.random.randn(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.params['b1'] = np.zeros(hidden_size)
        self.params['W2'] = std * np.random.randn(hidden_size, output_size)
        self.params['b2'] = np.zeros(output_size)

    def loss(self, X, y=None, reg=0.0):
        """
        Compute the loss and gradients for a two layer fully connected neural
        network.
        Inputs:
        - X: Input data of shape (N, D). Each X[i] is a training sample.
        - y: Vector of training labels. y[i] is the label for X[i], and each y[i] is
          an integer in the range 0 <= y[i] < C. This parameter is optional; if it
          is not passed then we only return scores, and if it is passed then we
          instead return the loss and gradients.
        - reg: Regularization strength.
        Returns:
        If y is None, return a matrix scores of shape (N, C) where scores[i, c] is
        the score for class c on input X[i].
        If y is not None, instead return a tuple of:
        - loss: Loss (data loss and regularization loss) for this batch of training
          samples.
        - grads: Dictionary mapping parameter names to gradients of those parameters
          with respect to the loss function; has the same keys as self.params.
        """
        # Unpack variables from the params dictionary
        W1, b1 = self.params['W1'], self.params['b1']
        W2, b2 = self.params['W2'], self.params['b2']
        N, D = X.shape

        # Compute the forward pass
        scores = None
        #############################################################################
        # TODO: Perform the forward pass, computing the class scores for the input. #
        # Store the result in the scores variable, which should be an array of      #
        # shape (N, C).                                                             #
        #############################################################################
        # *****START OF YOUR CODE (DO NOT DELETE/MODIFY THIS LINE)*****

        # perform the forward pass and compute the class scores for the input
        # input - fully connected layer - ReLU - fully connected layer - softmax
        
        # define lamba function for relu
        relu = lambda x: np.maximum(0, x)

        # a1 = X x W1 = (N x D) x (D x H) = N x H
        a1 = relu(X.dot(W1) + b1) # activations of fully connected layer #1

        # store the result in the scores variable, which should be an array of
        # shape (N, C).
        # scores = a1 x W2 = (N x H) x (H x C) = N x C
        scores = a1.dot(W2) + b2 # output of softmax

        # *****END OF YOUR CODE (DO NOT DELETE/MODIFY THIS LINE)*****

        # If the targets are not given then jump out, we're done
        if y is None:
            return scores

        # Compute the loss
        loss = None
        #############################################################################
        # TODO: Finish the forward pass, and compute the loss. This should include  #
        # both the data loss and L2 regularization for W1 and W2. Store the result  #
        # in the variable loss, which should be a scalar. Use the Softmax           #
        # classifier loss.                                                          #
        #############################################################################
        # *****START OF YOUR CODE (DO NOT DELETE/MODIFY THIS LINE)*****

        # shift values for 'scores' for numeric reasons (over-flow cautious)
        # figure out the max score across all classes
        # scores.shape is N x C
        scores -= scores.max(axis = 1, keepdims = True)

        # probs.shape is N x C
        probs = np.exp(scores)/np.sum(np.exp(scores), axis = 1, keepdims = True)

        loss = -np.log(probs[np.arange(N), y])

        # loss is a single number
        loss = np.sum(loss)   

        # Right now the loss is a sum over all training examples, but we want it
        # to be an average instead so we divide by N.
        loss /= N

        # Add regularization to the loss.
        loss += reg * (np.sum(W1 * W1) + np.sum(W2 * W2))

        # *****END OF YOUR CODE (DO NOT DELETE/MODIFY THIS LINE)*****

        # Backward pass: compute gradients
        grads = {}
        #############################################################################
        # TODO: Compute the backward pass, computing the derivatives of the weights #
        # and biases. Store the results in the grads dictionary. For example,       #
        # grads['W1'] should store the gradient on W1, and be a matrix of same size #
        #############################################################################
        # *****START OF YOUR CODE (DO NOT DELETE/MODIFY THIS LINE)*****

        # since dL(i)/df(k) = p(k) - 1 (if k = y[i]), where f is a vector of scores for the given example
        # i is the training sample and k is the class
        dscores = probs.reshape(N, -1) # dscores is (N x C)
        dscores[np.arange(N), y] -= 1

        # since scores = a1.dot(W2), we get dW2 by multiplying a1.T and dscores
        # W2 is H x C so dW2 should also match those dimensions
        # a1.T x dscores = (H x N) x (N x C) = H x C
        dW2 = np.dot(a1.T, dscores)

        # Right now the gradient is a sum over all training examples, but we want it
        # to be an average instead so we divide by N.
        dW2 /= N

        # b2 gradient: sum dscores over all N and C
        db2 = dscores.sum(axis = 0)/N

        # since a1 = X.dot(W1), we get dW1 by multiplying X.T and da1
        # W1 is D x H so dW1 should also match those dimensions
        # X.T x da1 = (D x N) x (N x H) = D x H

        # first get da1 using scores = a1.dot(W2)
        # a1 is N x H so da1 should also match those dimensions
        # dscores x W2.T = (N x C) x (C x H) = N x H
        da1 = dscores.dot(W2.T)
        da1[a1 == 0] = 0 # set gradient of units that did not activate to 0
        dW1 = X.T.dot(da1)

        # Right now the gradient is a sum over all training examples, but we want it
        # to be an average instead so we divide by N.
        dW1 /= N        

        # b1 gradient: sum da1 over all N and H
        db1 = da1.sum(axis = 0)/N        

        # Add regularization loss to the gradient
        dW1 += 2 * reg * W1     
        dW2 += 2 * reg * W2     

        grads = {'W1': dW1, 'b1': db1, 'W2': dW2, 'b2': db2}

        # *****END OF YOUR CODE (DO NOT DELETE/MODIFY THIS LINE)*****

        return loss, grads

    def train(self, X, y, X_val, y_val,
              learning_rate=1e-3, learning_rate_decay=0.95,
              reg=5e-6, num_iters=100,
              batch_size=200, verbose=False):
        """
        Train this neural network using stochastic gradient descent.
        Inputs:
        - X: A numpy array of shape (N, D) giving training data.
        - y: A numpy array f shape (N,) giving training labels; y[i] = c means that
          X[i] has label c, where 0 <= c < C.
        - X_val: A numpy array of shape (N_val, D) giving validation data.
        - y_val: A numpy array of shape (N_val,) giving validation labels.
        - learning_rate: Scalar giving learning rate for optimization.
        - learning_rate_decay: Scalar giving factor used to decay the learning rate
          after each epoch.
        - reg: Scalar giving regularization strength.
        - num_iters: Number of steps to take when optimizing.
        - batch_size: Number of training examples to use per step.
        - verbose: boolean; if true print progress during optimization.
        """
        num_train = X.shape[0]
        iterations_per_epoch = max(num_train / batch_size, 1)

        # Use SGD to optimize the parameters in self.model
        loss_history = []
        train_acc_history = []
        val_acc_history = []

        for it in range(num_iters):
            X_batch = None
            y_batch = None

            #########################################################################
            # TODO: Create a random minibatch of training data and labels, storing  #
            # them in X_batch and y_batch respectively.                             #
            #########################################################################
            # *****START OF YOUR CODE (DO NOT DELETE/MODIFY THIS LINE)*****

            # generate random indices
            indices = np.random.choice(num_train, batch_size)
            X_batch, y_batch = X[indices], y[indices]

            # *****END OF YOUR CODE (DO NOT DELETE/MODIFY THIS LINE)*****

            # Compute loss and gradients using the current minibatch
            loss, grads = self.loss(X_batch, y=y_batch, reg=reg)
            loss_history.append(loss)

            #########################################################################
            # TODO: Use the gradients in the grads dictionary to update the         #
            # parameters of the network (stored in the dictionary self.params)      #
            # using stochastic gradient descent. You'll need to use the gradients   #
            # stored in the grads dictionary defined above.                         #
            #########################################################################
            # *****START OF YOUR CODE (DO NOT DELETE/MODIFY THIS LINE)*****

            self.params['W1'] -= learning_rate * grads['W1']
            self.params['W2'] -= learning_rate * grads['W2']
            self.params['b1'] -= learning_rate * grads['b1']
            self.params['b2'] -= learning_rate * grads['b2']

            # *****END OF YOUR CODE (DO NOT DELETE/MODIFY THIS LINE)*****

            if verbose and it % 100 == 0:
                print('iteration %d / %d: loss %f' % (it, num_iters, loss))

            # Every epoch, check train and val accuracy and decay learning rate.
            if it % iterations_per_epoch == 0:
                # Check accuracy
                train_acc = (self.predict(X_batch) == y_batch).mean()
                val_acc = (self.predict(X_val) == y_val).mean()
                train_acc_history.append(train_acc)
                val_acc_history.append(val_acc)

                # Decay learning rate
                learning_rate *= learning_rate_decay

        return {
          'loss_history': loss_history,
          'train_acc_history': train_acc_history,
          'val_acc_history': val_acc_history,
        }

    def predict(self, X):
        """
        Use the trained weights of this two-layer network to predict labels for
        data points. For each data point we predict scores for each of the C
        classes, and assign each data point to the class with the highest score.
        Inputs:
        - X: A numpy array of shape (N, D) giving N D-dimensional data points to
          classify.
        Returns:
        - y_pred: A numpy array of shape (N,) giving predicted labels for each of
          the elements of X. For all i, y_pred[i] = c means that X[i] is predicted
          to have class c, where 0 <= c < C.
        """
        y_pred = None

        ###########################################################################
        # TODO: Implement this function; it should be VERY simple!                #
        ###########################################################################
        # *****START OF YOUR CODE (DO NOT DELETE/MODIFY THIS LINE)*****
        
        # define lamba function for relu
        relu = lambda x: np.maximum(0, x)
        
        # activations of fully connected layer #1
        a1 = relu(X.dot(self.params['W1']) + self.params['b1']) 

        # output of softmax
        # scores = a1 x W2 = (N x H) x (H x C) = N x C
        scores = a1.dot(self.params['W2']) + self.params['b2']
        y_pred = np.argmax(scores, axis = 1)

        # *****END OF YOUR CODE (DO NOT DELETE/MODIFY THIS LINE)*****

        return y_pred
```

My problem about the above code is in

```
loss = -np.log(probs[np.arange(N), y])
```

I understand from the code that  Probs is N*C and y is 1*C. First of all is the shape of y 1*C ?The above code must be correct because I took from a reliable source on github. However when I try very similar problem in my computer I get an error below is my code in my computer. Please explain me what is happenning in the loss I mentioned above, I have problem with dimensions.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnkBM.jpg)

I mentioned above what I tried very related to that problem. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1EM1.jpg)Also I am putting it here.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Cause your size of the array `a` is (2, 2)

```
print(a.shape)
```

> (2, 2)

That means the index is `0` and `1`, but in array `y` there is a `2`, where you try to slice an array of 2*2 with index 2, it's out of its range.

Just change your `y = np.array([[0, 1]])` or `y = np.array([[0, 0]])` or `y = np.array([[1, 1]])`, but not passing range of the index.